# Field value is null in Opportunity Product PopOut Screen crm 2013

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-2013

When i open an opportunity product screen from Opportunity.

[image]

I am able to get value from the following line

Xrm.Page.getAttribute("opportunityid").getValue()

But when i click on PopOut button

[image]

On load of that form the value of Xrm.Page.getAttribute("opportunityid").getValue() is null

Comment: If you are in a oppotunity and you "Add a new project product", then you automatically are setting the value of "opportunityid" with the parent. if elsewhere you make a "New project product" all the values will be clean, including "opportunityid". I guess this is your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no resolution available for this.
I have found this issue also in MS Dynamics CRM Vanilla 2013 version.

You have to wait till Microsoft gives the solution in their next roll up.